# How to traverse an array like a sine-wave?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Assume I had a 2D integer array, mxn.
I want to traverse this array like a sine wave.

In specific, traversal would start from the last row, and the first column, move onto the first row and the second column, move onto the last row and the third column.

I have attached an image to elaborate further.

[image: Sine-wave traversal]

t:
I only know how to traverse in order, but I was thinking of transposing the columns, changing the starting index of the column at every round, but I couldn't create a consisting loop to do so.

My attempt:

```
boolean startsAtbottom=true;
    //cols become rows, startPoint alternates
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(startsAtbottom)
        {
            for(int j =m-1;j>-1;j--)
            {
                System.out.print(myArr[j][i]);
            }
            startsAtbottom=false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int j =0;j<m;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(myArr[j][i]);
            }
            startsAtbottom=true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For questions similar to this, it's **always** best for you to show your best good-faith attempt at a solution. I'm betting that if you do this, you can either solve this, or get awful close. But without this, the question devolves into the realm of "homework dump". Please don't let it stay there.

Comment: I'll add my solution as an edit

Comment: Hint: work it out on paper first.

Comment: Don't mix trigonometry with a pattern to traverse an array. There is no minimal relation between the two.

Comment: What is wrong with your attempt? It looks right to me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its possible @Jack

Comment: @Bar: he's mentioning your title. Your question has nothing to do with sine waves, absolutely nothing at all.

Comment: @PaulBoddington mine works, but it uses 3 loops and if structures, I want a single solution, if possible

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you want. All you want is to change the way you traverse in consecutive iterations.

```
boolean traverseInOrder=true;
for(int i=0;i<columnCount;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<rowCount;j++){
        index=j;
        if(!traverseInOrder){
            index=rowCount-j-1;
        }

        //access the element
        int element=array[i][index];
    }
    traverseInOrder= !traverseInOrder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works, and there's nothing wrong with it. However you can get rid of the `if` by doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    boolean goingUp = i % 2 == 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        int row = goingUp ? m - 1 - j : j;
        System.out.println(myArr[row][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is necessary to compute `i % 2` outside the inner loop. Being a loop-invariant it is eligible for loop-invariant code motion optimizations. If you placed it outside for stylistical purpose then it's different.

Comment: @Jack I'm never sure with things like that whether it's computed once or repeatedly. I'm assuming if I wrote something like `boolean goingUp = Math.sin(i) < 0.5;` that would get computed repeatedly unless I did it outside the inner loop. As I'm never sure I always do this kind of thing as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your input you have that:

- the outer loop index just increments from `0`
- the inner loop index increments for even columns and decrements for odd columns
- you can determine if a number is even or odd by just checking if modulo is 0 (or by checking if `(i & 0x01) == 0` but that's irrelevant)

Given this it's quite easy to model that pattern:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
    int value = data[i][i % 2 == 0 ? (cols - j - 1) : j]
  }
}
```

The formula `cols - j - 1` allows you to start from the end and go backward (see that with `j = 0` you have `cols - 1` and with `j = cols - 1` you have `cols - (cols - 1) - 1 == 0`).

Mind that Java is nor column major nor row major, since a bidimensional array is just an array of arrays so according to your real layout you may need to swap indices.